# Summarize Pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gensim

I have a large dataframe (~4.7M rows) where one of the columns contains document text. I am trying unsuccessfully to run Gensim summarize on a specific column for the entire dataframe.

```py
df['summary'] = df['variable_content'].apply(lambda x: summarize(x, word_count=200))
```

Extracting each row of `variable_content` into a variable and running summarize works well, but is slow and ugly. I also get the error:

```
ValueError: input must have more than one sentence
```

but can't find a row with only one sentence (most are hundreds/thousands). Can anyone help?

Comment: As to the ValueError: replace the lambda with a 'real' function, and catch this exception within the function. If the exception occurs, print the content. That would indicate where the error is.

Comment: As to 'slow' - trying parallelizing.

Comment: You haven't stated what was unsuccessful with your column-based approach. (Did you get an error? A crash? Not see any, or acceptable, results?) If using a separate loop/list is slow, it's likely any approach will be similarly slow – the same amount of calculation needs to be done either way. (Though, if your question were clearly, "this exact code works but is too slow, can I speed it up?", some suggestions might be possible, if there are any errors in the code or opportunities for things like multicore parallelization.)

Comment: To have any chance of knowing what in your code, and your data, might be causing the "must have more than one sentence", you'd need to show your code, the full error stack you've received, and ideally some example data that triggers the error. (You can probably edit your code to write either the text, or row-number, when the error is raised.)

Comment: But ultimately: you may not be happy with `gensim.summarization` results, unless you've already tested it on some representative texts & been happy. It's a very crude approach, that uses its own idiosyncratic & not-very-efficient sentence/word tokenization & then tries to pick a subset of full sentences that mention a lot of the text's repeated words. If the texts were already well-written to include some internal summary sentences, it *might* find them, but the limits of its algorithm, and only returning exact sentences from the original, keep most 'summaries' from being very impressive.

Comment: @gojomo thank you for your feedback. Gensim summarization is a _dramatic_ improvement over the current summarization, so while you are probably correct, initial reviews with my users sent them over the moon.

Comment: @gojomo As you guessed, there ended up being more than one error - most were related to dirty data. Taking advice from Roy2012 I used a generic function in try-except format and the filthy dirtiness of allegedly clean data became apparent. Cleaning and filtering that data took care of most of the failures (tttt I added 'pass' at the end of exception handling to complete the loop. I then filtered out the hard failures to review later this week.

Comment: @Roy2012 I am dask'ing it now and it seems to be successful with a development dataset. I'll post the code once I can report on a larger dataset success.

Comment: Cool! Great to hear.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4.7 million rows, each of which has hundreds or thousands of sentences, and you expect this to work in finite time? That's what I call "optimism". I would suggest looping through your dataframe and running your thing in chunks of, say 1000 rows, saving the work as you go along, and printing out the number of the chunk as you go along. Once it fails, you will know roughly where the failure was, plus you will actually get some results.

Comment: I created a devset of 1000 rows to work through the processing logic, because, as you note 4.7M rows is slow. I also ran 'langdetect' on the dataset, which removed 50 or so rows as not being English (believing it is possible that summarize and my brain work best on English. I'll do a row-by-row loop and see what happens.

Comment: @user2366762 Row by row is fine here, since the amount of computation per row is high, but I was suggesting something like 

     for i in range(0, len(df), 1000):
        newdf = df.iloc[i:i+1000]
        ...do your thing